# use dplyr to summarize first element of a nested list (2-d array?)

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, purrr, tibble

i'm trying to understand the appropriate usage of dplyr on summarizing a nested list within a tibble.

The structure is as follows:

```
> glimpse(mydata)
Rows: 1,000
Columns: 3
$ meta                 <df[,6]> <data.frame[40 x 6]>
$ independent_variable <list> [<"A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A…
$ dependent_variables  <df[,4]> <data.frame[40 x 4]>


> head(mydata$independent_variable)
[[1]]
      [,1]        [,2]    [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "A" "FALSE" "5" NA  
 [2,] "B"  "FALSE" "5" "NA"
 [3,] "B"  "FALSE" "5" "NA"
 [4,] "B"  "FALSE" "5" "NA"
 [5,] "A"  "FALSE" "13" "NA"
 [6,] "A"  "FALSE" "5" "NA"
 [7,] "B"  "FALSE" "12" "NA" 
 [8,] "A"  "FALSE" "133 "NA"
 [9,] "A"  "FALSE" "131 "NA"
[10,] "A"  "TRUE"  "0"  "NA" 

[[2]]
     [,1]        [,2]    [,3] [,4] 
[1,] "A" "FALSE" "77" NA   
[2,] "B"  "FALSE" NA   "NA"
[3,] "B"  "FALSE" NA   "NA" 
[4,] "B"  "FALSE" NA   "NA" 
[5,] "B"  "FALSE" NA   "NA"
[6,] "A"  "TRUE"  "1"  "NA"
```

the independent_variable is a 1000 entries of N x 4 listings (that is, all 1000 entries have 4 columns, and varying number of rows. the first column is the only column im currently interested in reviewing, and each element can only be either "A" or "B").  I want to count the number of "A"'s within each of the 1000 and get that value back for each of the 1000 entries.

it seems like i should use purrr, but i'm not sure how to structure this in dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using purrr:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# my example data
tmp = list(cbind(c("A","A","B"),1),cbind(c("B","A","B"),2))

# define a summary function
count_A = function(x){
  x %>%
    as.data.frame() %>% # needed as the input data is of type 'matrix'
    select(V1) %>%      # the default column name for column 1
    filter(V1 == "A") %>%
    ungroup() %>%       # unnecessary, but clear you are summarising the whole df
    summarise(num_A = n())
}

# test summary function
count_A(tmp[[1]])

# apply function to every element of list
map(tmp, count_A)
```

In this pattern, your summary function can be any function that takes a single argument and returns the desired result. If the function works correctly when applied to the first element of the list (see in the code, I test my summary function) then you can expect that map will apply the function to every element of the list.